# System.Windows.Freezable is missing

Tags: c#, wpf, class, dll, brush

I have got a Class Library project where I keep some interfaces and classes for my WPF Application and RIA Services.

Into the one of class I want to add a member

```
Brush BackgroundColor { set; get; }
```

or

```
SolidColorBrush BackgroundColor { set; get; }
```

But I got this error.

> Error 2   The type 'System.Windows.Freezable' is defined in an assembly
>   that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly
>   'WindowsBase, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'.

What's up?

How to fix it if under *Add Reference* window I cannot see that assembly at all?

Comment: Sorry for stupid question but have you installed .NET 4.0?

Comment: What version of .NET does your class library target?

Comment: @sll yup! :) I have installed .NET 4.0

Comment: @Peretz: In that case, WindowsBase should definitely be listed in the AddReference window... are you seeing the other normal "system" assemblies?

Comment: Note that the list of .net assemblies is not sorted....

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The solution is simple.  Just add references to the following three DLLs:

**WindowsBase.dll**

**PresentationFramework.dll**

**PresentationCore.dll**

In .Net 4.5, these DLL's typically reside in a directory with a name similar to:  C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5

Comment: Why?  Why in the world would I have to do this?